# Convert Excel sheet to PDF through Java

Tags: java, excel

I need to convert an excel spreadsheet to PDF file. I looked for in the Web and I found that the best way to do this is using OpenOffice API, but it is not free.

Someone know any open source library for doing this?

Any examples code is appreciating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) can read Excel. [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/) can write PDF.

Comment: There are numerous examples on the web of how to read Excel via POI. For instance: http://www.kodejava.org/examples/461.html

There are also many examples of how to create a PDF using iText, for example: http://www.roseindia.net/java/itext/index.shtml

In the end, though, you will need to provide the glue code between the two. This will depend on your business needs.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  A coworker wanted to convert excel to pdf via a script on a unix box and did NOT want the hassle of waiting for a big, slow, bureaucratic IT department to install open office on it just so he could get the APIs for data conversion.  Your links helped me make a low hassle solution for him.

Comment: can iText handle styling of the cells?